# How to create a compound JSON object from these three models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, database-design, model, rails-models

I have three tables; `Area`, `Movie` and `MovieArea`. In rails, I want to be able to query `MovieArea` based on the `area_id` field of `Movie`. I then want to return a compound json object using the fields from `Movie` and replacing the fields of the same names with the values from `MovieArea`.

I have the following database structure:

[image]

And the following models:

```
class Movie < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :title, :synopsis, :grossing, :director, :year, :facts
    has_many :movie_areas, :class_name => 'MovieArea'
end

class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :name
    has_many :movie_areas, :class_name => 'MovieArea'
end

class MovieArea < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :movie_id, :area_id, :synopsis, :facts

    belongs_to :area, :class_name => 'Area', :foreign_key => :area_id
    belongs_to :movie, :class_name => 'Movie', :foreign_key => :movie_id
end
```

Finally, I have been attempting to create this object by using model methods and altering the JSON response. To the model adding:

```
def grossing
    self.movie.grossing
end
def year
    self.movie.year
end
def title
    self.movie.title
end
```

etc.. And in the controller:

```
@results = MovieArea.where(:area_id => @area.id)
```

Finally, in the view:

```
<%= @results.to_json(:methods => [:grossing, :year, :title] ).html_safe -%>
```

This works fine and I get the type of JSON object I want:

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "area_id":1,
      "movie_id":1,
      "synopsis":"Area relevant movie synopsis",
      "facts":"Area relevant movie facts",
      "grossing":"$9001M",
      "year":"1999",
      "title":"Movie title",
   },
   .....
]
```

So the question is: Is there a better way to do this? For example, could I output it all from the model and call something like `MovieArea.where(:area_id => @area.id).some_function_to_respond` ? Or can I move the logic to the controller so in the view it simply calls `@results.to_json()`?

Thank you!

Comment: have you looked at jbuilder? https://github.com/rails/jbuilder

Comment: [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) is good for generating JSON or XML

Answer (score 0):

There is a very recent RailsCasts episode covering what you would like to do. Take a look at it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using [RABL](https://github.com/nesquena/rabl) - thanks for the recommendation [shweta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/867590/shweta). I installed it by adding the following to my Gemfile and running `bundle install` to install it.

```
gem 'rabl'
gem 'oj'
```

I then created the following RABL template `movie_areas.json.rabl` in a `views/rabl` folder:

```
object @movie
attributes :id, :synopsis, :facts
glue :movie do
  attributes :title, :grossing, :director, :year
end
```

The above code takes the `id`, `synopsis` and `facts` from the `movie_area` table and then adds in the `title`, `grossing`, `director` and `year` from the parent `movie`.

To render out the JSON direct in a view, which I require for use in backbone.js, I call:

```
<%= Rabl.render(@results, 'rabl/movie_areas').html_safe -%>
```

Where `@results` is the variable ActiveRecord query defined in my question and `rabl/movie_areas` refers to the `movie_areas.json.rabl` template.

To output direct from a controller for an API, I use:

```
def movies
    @area = Area.find_by_slug(params[:slug])
    @results = MovieArea.where(:area_id => @area.id)
    render :inline => Rabl::Renderer.json(@results, 'rabl/movie_areas')
end
```

Hopefully this will help someone out in the future!